# What does the parameter s in Sum-of-Gamma mean?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, gamma-distribution, gumbel-distribution

So the sum of gamma, introduced in [I-MLE](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/file/7a430339c10c642c4b2251756fd1b484-Paper.pdf) is defined as the following:

$$SoG(k,t,s)=\frac{t}{k} \left( \sum^{s}_{i=1} Gamma(1/k,k/i) - \log(s) \right)$$

But what exactly is $s$? It clearly controls the number of sums of Gamma we're performing, which also controls the beta factor in the Gamma function... but what exactly does this mean? If we have $k=5$ and $s=10$ does that mean we're producing a distribution for top-5 of 10 classes?

Comment: SoG() is not a standard function in statistics, so you need to cite where it has been defined. I am guessing you are reading the following proceedings paper from 2021: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/file/7a430339c10c642c4b2251756fd1b484-Paper.pdf. It isn't very likely that other readers will be familiar with this (somewhat obscure) paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: Yes, if $k$ = 5 and $s$ = 10, then the sum of gamma function would be calculated using the gamma function for the top-5 items out of a total of 10 items.

Explanation: The variable, $s$, is the number of terms in the sum of the gamma function, (which in turn determines the precision of the calculation). When $s$ is larger, the sum of gamma function will be a more accurate approximation of the true gamma function.

In the context of a top-$k$ distribution, $k$ would typically represent the number of items you want to select (e.g., the top-5 items), and $s$ would then represent the total number of items to choose from (e.g., 10 classes).